# "Clone" vagrant box to development server

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, digital-ocean, homestead

I use vagrant in my development machine (LARAVEL HOMESTEAD). I wonder how to set up my production server (ex digital ocean) exactly like the vagrant box.

Maybe convert de vagrant file in a shell script...

Comment: Look at configuration management tools like puppet or chef.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vagrant package` when the machine is powered off.

The package.box contains the full virtual machine, compressed. You can put this file whereever you want now.

With `vagrant init` you can initialize a new default Vagrantfile.
In this Vagrantfile you should edit the following line with the your path:

```
config.vm.box_url = "http://example.com/path/to/your_box.box"
```

Note that this can also be a local path like:

```
config.vm.box_url = "file:///d:/path/to/your_box.box"
```